# Date validation plugin without calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

We're launching a new content management system and redoing our user input forms in a way that allows the marketing department total control over what is displayed, in what order etc. I really want to use the jquery ui datepicker plugin because we can basically plug in its validation rules directly into the CMS, allowing for a fully customizeable control without any dev input. I've showed it off and shown how easy it is to configure.

Our current forms use three different drop downs, one each for day, month and year. There are a few people who aren't budging on moving away from this look/feel. We've all seen them, one of these guys:

```
<select>
    <option value="">-- Month --</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">etc.</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="">-- Day --</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">etc.</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    <option value="etc.">etc.</option>                        
</select>
```

I can implement this, no doubt. What I don't want to do is write and maintain a javascript library that translates rules from a CMS into js inputs -- there has to be a better way.

I've shown them the month/year drop down selectors in the jquery ui plugin: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year but they're still not buying it. Something about showing the days of the month... stakeholders.

What I want to know is if there is an existing configurable plugin that matches/rivals the jquery UI plugin in configurability and give the 3-select form factor. I'm making particular use of the `mindate`, `maxdate` (for different date ranges for different input types), and `altformat` options (to automatically translate the submission format that our backend expects). Sorry if my frustration is coming out... and thanks for the input.

Edit: just remembered there's a separate UI/UX area on stack exchange. My apologies if this is better suited over there - I don't have an account there yet.

Comment: I think this belongs here, it seems more coding than design...

Comment: While it's commonly unwise to tell stakeholders 'no', you CAN make them aware of the costs/implications of their decisions.  Tell them how long it will take you to correctly code and maintain the 3 selects vs. how long it will take to implement the datepicker.

Comment: I read this topic twice and I don't fully understand what it is you are trying to do and how the current answers are not giving you satisfying results. Can you provide more feedback into your actual scenario ?

Comment: try Yahoo ui: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/calendar-multipane.html

Comment: @Khez Just an hour before your comment, there was exactly one answer :-) I'll try out a few of these suggestions and see if I can share something close to what I want in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your question title, you could look into **datejs** for all your date parsing, validation and incrementing.

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Comment: +1 This shows promise. I had previously found the `Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>` for date formatting, but this looks like it will have more of the range checking I'll need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that there's already something perfectly suited for what you need.

You can however, use [date-utils](https://github.com/JerrySievert/node-date-utils), which will simplify your validation. Here are some examples taken from the documentation:

```
Date.validateDay(day, year, month); // true/false whether a date is valid

d.between(date1, date2); // true/false if the date/time is between date1 and date2
d.isBefore(date); // true/false, true if this is before date passed
d.isAfter(date); // true/false, true if this is after date passed

d.toFormat(format); // returns date formatted with...
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [this](http://www.ancientgeek.co.uk/2009/05/21/jquery-datepicker-widget-with-drop-downs/)?

The link of the example is [here](http://www.ancientgeek.co.uk/datepicker-example.html).

Comment: I tried it out, but it's still backwards of my ideal use case. That's driving a datepicker calendar widget from some drop downs. It can't auto-populate or limit the drop downs from the datepicker options at all. I might use a small part of their example code, but it doesn't really save anything over a fully custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/#display=inline&demo=date&mode=scroller&theme=sense-ui) which will still provides all the features of drop-down like feel without compromising on looks .

[image: mobiScroll]

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one that really doesn't like using them.

Comment: Why dont you like using them ?

Comment: When deselected it takes up more room than 3 separate drop-downs. When selected it shows me fewer options than a drop-down. While its not designed for a mouse as much as touch screens it takes more clicks to get to the values I'm after. When using a touch screen it is much easier to slide past the value you wanted to choose.

Comment: True but it surely looks cool, By the way
You can use the scroll wheel on the mouse to get to any point faster.

IMHO stakeholders seem to prefer cool over actual usability.

Comment: Unfortunately, I totally agree with you there.

Comment: The main requirement I've been given is that it basically needs to look bad (in my humble opinion). It's three drop downs or else. I'm just looking for something that can automatically configure ranges and validate inputs.